# How to echo gdal process to screen and pipe to text file in Windows?

Tags: gdal, windows, bat

gdal_warp and similar give a nice progress summary when run and I want this output to show in the osgeo shell and also pipe to a text file. The issue is when I add the pipe the output doesn't show on the screen. How can I do both?

```
gdal_translate -expand rgba -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:3857 -co TILED=YES -co BIGTIFF=YES %1 %2\%3\%3_translated.tif > %2\%3\%3_translate_log.txt
```

puts the output to a text file but then doesn't show the progress on screen.

I tried

```
Echo gdal_translate -expand rgba -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:3857 -co TILED=YES -co BIGTIFF=YES %1 %2\%3\%3_translated.tif > %2\%3\%3_translate_log.txt
```

and

```
Echo.gdal_translate -expand rgba -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:3857 -co TILED=YES -co BIGTIFF=YES %1 %2\%3\%3_translated.tif > %2\%3\%3_translate_log.txt
```

but neither works.

Comment: first to ' echo "command line with spaces" >> file.txt ' and after that execute command line in bat file (or do like i do, i got bash shell from git package and i do all my scripts in bash)

Comment: I don't understand <<echo "gdal_translate -expand rgba -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:3857 -co TILED=YES -co BIGTIFF=YES %1 %2\%3\%3_translated.tif" > %2\%3\1_%3_translate_log.txt
>> just prints the line in the log.txt file.

Comment: sorry, my bad i didn't understand question right. See R.K answer. it is working way to do it

Answer (score 2):

Found this workaround at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1141753/414389)

```
gdal_translate -expand rgba -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:3857 -co TILED=YES -co BIGTIFF=YES %1 %2\%3\%3_translated.tif >> %2\%3\%3_translate_log.txt | type a.txt %2\%3\%3_translate_log.txt
```

A caveat, this will echo to screen after it has been saved to file.

Or you can [install a Windows port of the tee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/796492/414389) command that should do what you want.

Comment: thanks...the main reason for this question is to be able to see what's happening with the gdal_warp/retile.py etc as they give an output "0...10...20" or "pyramid 1012 created" etc. I can also just open the txt file and it still writes to it. I don't want to install tee or cygwin as getting gdal/python to work in it is very complex...can we echo the output to the shell and then pipe that to a txt file?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can do that on Windows. There can only be one output if I'm not mistaken. I think `tee` isn't too complex. The format is just ` mycommand > tee outpu_file.txt` which should direct output to stdout and the file.